# Calculating the adjacency matrix and finding nearest neighbors for different node type/classes

Tags: python, graph-theory, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Before I describe my problem I'll summarise what I *think* I'm looking for. I *think* I need a method for nearest-neighbor searches which are restricted by node type in python (In my case a node represents an atom and the node type represents the element the atom is). So only returning the nearest neighbors of a given type. Maybe I am wording my problem incorrectly. I haven't been able to find any existing methods for this.

I am writing some ring statistics code to find different types of rings for molecular dynamics simulation data. The input data structure is a big array of atom id, atom type, and XYZ positions.

For example.

[image: Example of input data]

At the moment I only consider single-element systems (for example graphene, so only Carbon atoms are present). So each node is considered the same type when finding its nearest neighbors and calculating the adjacency matrix.

For this, I am using KDTree and scipy.spatial algorithms and find all atoms within the bond length, r, from any given atom. If an atom is within, r radius of a given atom I consider it connected and then populate and update an adjacency dictionary accordingly.

```
def create_adjacency_dict(data, r, leaf_size=5, box_size=None):
    from scipy.spatial import KDTree
    tree = KDTree(data, leafsize=leaf_size,
                  boxsize=box_size)  
    all_nn_indices = tree.query_ball_point(data, r, workers=5)  # Calculates neighbours within radius r of a point.
    adj_dict = {}
    for count, item in enumerate(all_nn_indices):
        adj_dict[count] = item  # Populate adjacency dictionary

    for node, nodes in adj_dict.items():
        if node in nodes:
            nodes.remove(node)  # Remove duplicates

    adj_dict = {k: set(v) for k, v in adj_dict.items()}

    return adj_dict
```

I would like to expand the code to deal with multi-species systems. For example AB<sub>2</sub>, AB<sub>2</sub>C<sub>4</sub> etc (Where A,B and C represent different atomic species). However, I am struggling to figure out a nice way to do this.

```
                                             A
                                            / \
                                           B   B
```

The obvious method would be to just do a brute force Euclidean approach. My idea is to input the bond types for a molecule, so for AB<sub>2</sub> (shown above), you would input something like AB to indicate the different types of bonds to consider, and then the respective bond lengths. Then loop over each atom finding the distance to all other atoms and, for this example of AB<sub>2</sub>, if an atom of type A is within the bond length of an atom B, consider them connected and populate the adjacency matrix. However, I'd like to be able to use the code on large datasets of 50,000+ atoms, so this method seems wasteful.

I suppose I could still use my current method, but just search for say the 10 nearest neighbors of a given atom and then do a Euclidean search for each atom pair, following the same approach as above. Still seems like a better method would already exist though.

Do better methods already exist for this type of problem? Finding nearest neighbors restricted by node type? Or maybe someone knows a more correct wording of my problem, which is I think one of my issues here.

Answer (score 0):

"Then search the data."

This sounds like that old cartoon where someone points to a humourously complex diagram with a tiny label in the middle that says "Here a miracle happens"

[image]

Seriously, I am guessing that this searching is what you need to optimize ( you do not exactly say )

In turn, this suggests that you are doing a linear search through every atom and calculating the distance of each.  Could it be so!?

There is a standard answer for this problem, called an octree.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree

A netflix tv miniseries 'The Billion Dollar Code' dramatizes the advantages of this approach https://www.netflix.com/title/81074012

Comment: Yes exactly, just looping over the atoms and finding atom pair distances. I added some extra information to the question to hopefully clarify this. But to summarize what I want to optimize, I basically need a method that finds the nearest neighbors of specific atom types, instead of arbitrarily finding the nearest neighbors of any atom type.

Comment: " just search for say the 10 nearest neighbors of a given atom"  Yes.  The best way to do that is an octree.

Comment: "code on large datasets of 50,000+ atoms" For such datasets python is going to be far too slow.  You will need to use a compiled coding language e.g. C++ to get decent performance.